# Suggestion of books

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, general-topology, reference-request, book-recommendation

Respected all members, I want to read a book(Abstract algebra, Real analysis, Topology) in which each mathematical concepts is related with real life. Book which is totally based on application. I know some mathematics concepts are abstract in sense. But when a college student curiously ask me why we study all these concepts despite of these have no practical point of view. Sometimes I respond to students these concepts you learned at college level you will use in you phd. But sometimes I am unable to give satisfactory response to them. So please suggest me some mathematics book practical point of view where mathematical concepts is related. Thanks

Comment: A bit of topic, but [*Counting Surfaces*](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783764387969) is a book that describes the structures of surfaces arised from matrix culmulents.  Random matrices are a topic that makes use of many branches of math.  I didn't make it an answer because that won't suit high school students.

Comment: Most mathematical concepts simply have nothing to do with real like - the answer to the student's question is that it's useful for other math. (Take trig, for example. If differential equations I tell them that they were lied to - trig is not important because it lets you "solve triangles", it's important because it gives solutions to $y''+y=0$, and/or a "basis" for periodic functions...)

Comment: Polya theory of counting. It allows you to count objects with symmetry (such as necklaces with colored beads) using group theory.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps that *For All Practical Purposes: Introduction to Contemporary Mathematics* (W. H. Freeman) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Sir, please sent me link to download this book.

Comment: I don't think it is available online.

Comment: Ok sir. Suggest me if possible ,  similar type of books which are available online.